# pandas groupby access last group

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame looking like this:

```
date      info          
A         x
A         y 
B         z
B         x
C         y
```

I only want to know the last date. In this case it is C.

I thought that I can get this by grouping and sorting by the `Date` column:

```
 df.groupby('date', sort=True)
```

... and then accessing the last group. However, there is no way of accessing the last group as one-liner? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I was just over-complicating things.
to get C this should be enough:

```
df['date'].max()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the date as a value, your own answer is fine. But if you want to get the actual record with biggest date, you can use [`head()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
In [4]: df.sort('date', ascending=False).head(1)
Out[4]: 
  date info
4    C    y
```

You can also use `ascending` parameter to sort by other columns.

```
In [4]: df.sort(columns=['date', 'info'], ascending=[False, True]).head(1)
Out[4]: 
  date info
4    C    y
```

Comment: You want `tail` for the last rows

Comment: well I ordered `desc` by date, so `head` will work :) But you're right, `tail` could be more descriptive. I always translate the task to SQL in my head, and in SQL there's only `top n` keyword.

Comment: @EdChum BTW do you know if it's possible to do partial sort in pandas? For example, in this case we don't want to sort the whole dataframe, we just want to take `k` largest. So if we could do partial heapsort on the dataframe it would be nice

Comment: Not off the top of my head you'd have to write your own code I think, `sort` does support `kind='heapsort'` as a sort type, there is a similar bit of code here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2995 which may lead you to an answer

Comment: Thanks, also just found this one, could be useful, but still requires some wrapper code at the least - http://berkeleyanalytics.com/bottleneck/reference.html#bottleneck.partsort

Comment: That's a useful link thanks, may be worth an enhancement request on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)